# Issue with C++ file not finding included library

Tags: c++, glfw

I am working on learning C++ development and I wanted to have a file that can be used to create a window. When I run my build, it completes without an error and both CLion and Copilot have been unable to find any sort of errors. But when I run my main.cpp file, it says that my Window.cpp is unable to find the GLFW/glfw3.h file.

My CMakeLists.txt file looks like this below:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
    project(Mako)

    add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/glfw-3.4")
    include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/glfw-3.4/include/GLFW")

    find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

    set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp
        Window.cpp
        Window.h
    )

    add_library(Mako ${SOURCE_FILES})

    target_link_libraries(Mako glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
```

My code isn't anything spectacular honestly, I have a Window.cpp and Window.h file as well as a main.cpp which I'm using to test. I'm curious if I need to include the GLFW/glfw3.h file in my Window.h file but I'm not sure how to map that correctly as I am just starting to learn C++ and it's entirely reasonable I'm just being an idiot and not creating the files correctly and don't need the Window.h file and it's just causing main.cpp to become confused.

Window.cpp

```
    #include "Window.h"
    #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
    #include <cstdio>

    namespace graphics
    {
        Window *Window::getInstance() { ... }
        void Window::init_window() { ... }
    }
```

Window.h

```
    
    #ifndef MAKO_WINDOW_H
    #define MAKO_WINDOW_H

    namespace graphics
    {
    class Window
    {
        Window* window;
        public:
            static Window* getInstance();
            static void init_window();
            void error_callback(int error, const char* description);
    };
    }
    
#endif //MAKO_WINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
    #include "Window.cpp"

    using namespace graphics;

    int main() {
        graphics::Window::init_window();
        return 0;
    }
```

I've tried including the GLFW/glfw3.h file in my Window.h file but ran into an issue with it not being able to find the library but the Window.cpp file is. I would expect to be able to create an instance of the Window class in main.cpp.

Comment: I am not sure if `${GLFW_LIBRARIES}` gets populated if you don't use find_package()

Comment: Why are you including a cpp file? Include the header instead

Comment: Unrelated: Looks like `graphics::Window` is intended to be a Singleton. [Do it with a Meyers Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/4581301) and you're a lot less likely to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: 1) Drop the `/GLFW` from your `include_directories` call. 2) add_executable instead of add_library 3) don't #include Window.cpp

Comment: 4) Use a package manager like vcpkg or conan until you learn enough CMake to stop cargo culting. 5) Everything is relative to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` by default, no need to repeat yourself. 6) the glfw CMake build system already defines a `glfw` target you can link to that contains both header files and link flags.

Comment: On re-read, the source of your troubles is probably trying to "run" main.cpp. You should build with CMake and *run the generated `Mako` program  instead*.

Comment: @Botje Thank you! I followed your advice and resolved my issue, I would definitely like to avoid using package managers until I understand CMake.

Comment: Building third party libraries yourself is occasionally very painful. Study [modern cmake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/) and the linked resources.